# How to get data from a select box thats dynamically loading

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, selenium, drop-down-menu

I have a dropdown as in the pic below. Its having a "More..."option clicking which shall load the next ten data. On the next click of more, another 10 data will be loaded..similarly the whole list loads. How to access the entire list after loading everything.

[image]

```
  Select select=new Select(element);
        List<WebElement> options= select.getOptions();
int j=0;
    for(WebElement ele:options)
                {
                    str=ele.getText();
                    if(str.contains("More"))
                    {  
                     //this is to click the "More.." using selenium 
                    Actions action = new Actions(BaseClass.driver);
                    action.moveToElement(Filter.FilterApplied(),200, 0).click().build().perform();
                    Filter.FilterApplied().sendKeys(str);
                    action.moveToElement(Filter.FilterApplied()).click().build().perform(); 

                    //to assign newly loaded list to a new array
                   Select  se=new Select(Filter.FilterApplied());
                    options2=se.getOptions();
                    System.out.println("size of new list"+options2.size());

                    }
                    }
```

with this code I am able to click and load the list in the page once..but not able to copy the newly loaded list to anothe object. options2.size() gives the same old arraylist size as the old array list is again loading into options2. Why is that so? New arraylist should load right?
This I tried with selenium . Any method is fine ..maybe JQuery has a more efficient method??Please do tell. I just need to access the list which is initially not fully loaded in the page but loads as we click more.

HTML:

```
<select id="filterSel" name="filterSel" class="fixed-size" onchange="fnLoadAccountslegEnt(this.value); " onclick="closeDropDown();" size="1" style="top: 6.5px; margin: 0px; width: 58%; height: 30px;">
<option value=""></option>
<option value="a">Account:00</option>
<option value="a0">Account:0</option>
<option value="More" style="color: blue;">More...</option>
</select>
```

Initially this will be there.On clicking "More" other options are loading,like this. Its just having title extra than other options:

```
<select id="filterSel" name="filterSel" class="fixed-size" onchange="fnLoadAccountslegEnt(this.value); " onclick="closeDropDown();" size="1" style="top: 6.5px; margin: 0px; width: 58%; height: 30px;">
<option value=""></option>
<option value="a">Account:00</option>
<option value="a0">Account:0</option>
<option value="a1" title="Account: 1">Account: 1</option>
<option value="a2" title="Account: 10 ">Account: 10 </option>   
<option value="More" style="color: blue;">More...</option>
</select>
```

Comment: can you post html for the same?

Comment: @kushalツ  I have added the HTML

Comment: you can try something like `Select select=new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("close")));

while(select.getOptions().contains("More")){

select.selectByVisibleText("More...");

}

List<WebElement> options= select.getOptions(); `

Comment: @kushalツ Need to click more option to load further. SelectByVisibleText only selects right? It doesnt click

Comment: Yes that's true; I just wanted to check what happens when you select "More.." item using selenium, does it expand or gets selected?

Comment: It doesn't  expand only select

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use following method to click all `More` options occurring in the dropDown:

```
public static void clickMoreDropDownElement(WebDriver driver){

    Select select=new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("filterSel")));

    //while(select.getOptions().contains("More")){

        List<WebElement> allElements = select.getOptions();

        Iterator<WebElement> itr = allElements.iterator();

        while(itr.hasNext()){

            WebElement currentElement = itr.next();


            if(currentElement.getText().equals("More...")){

                currentElement.click();

                System.out.println("Clicked More..");

                clickMoreDropDownElement(driver);
            }
        }

}
```

once you have done that, you can store all Elements as following:

```
List<WebElement> options= select.getOptions();
```